# Else if structure gives the wrong output

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, solidity-0.5.x

I have a little problem with a else if struture that doesn't give out the right result.

Here is the code:

```
pragma solidity  >=0.5.16;

contract SupChain{
    
    enum StateType {A, B, C}
    
    function elseIf(string memory houseA, string memory houseB, 
                    int a, int b, int c) public view returns(StateType){
         StateType orderState;
        if(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(houseA))==keccak256(abi.encodePacked(houseB))){
            orderState = StateType.C;
        }else if(a < b || a > c){
            orderState = StateType.B;
        }else if(orderState != StateType.B){
            orderState = StateType.A;
        }
        return orderState;
    }
}
```

Let's says I use the following values:

houseA = 'Little';

houseB = 'Little';

a= 10;

b = -5;

c = 5;

Normally the function should return me the `state B` (the number 1) as an output since here a>c. However, when tested I get the `state C` (the number 2) as an output.

[image]

I thank in advance anybody who will help me.

Comment: There's a lot of (probably) redundant code. Could you create a minimal example which reproduces the problem - it would be a lot easier for any reader to digest. And, in my experience, reducing the problem to a simpler one often reveals the problem already.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen Okay, thanks for the advice, I have done it more correctly now. It should be easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works exactly as expected. Using your input, `houseA` and `houseB` are equal, so your code will pass on the first if-statement and return `StateType.C` (2) as expected.

When using a different value for `houseB`, `StateType.B` (1) is returned.

Comment: Thanks now I better understand what I should do to get the result that I want. I just need to but first else if in place of the if to get higher priority :D!